# Будет ли доступ к моему API

Tags: node.js, rest, angular, express

У меня есть сайт. Back-end (Express.js) и Front-end (Angular) отделены друг от друга, т.е работают на разных портах и запросы идут от Фронта (`localhost:4200`) к Беку (`localhost:3000`).
Если я сделаю сайт в открытый доступ, будет ли доступ к моему беку из вне, т.е смогут ли к нему обращаться вне фронтенда? Если да, то каким способом решаются данные проблемы?

Comment: Всегда смогут, ничто не мешает сделать поддельный фронт

Comment: @andreymal , не знаете какие-нибудь способы ограничить доступ? Может ли помочь отправка запросов с секретным ключём (токеном), который бекенд часть будет считывать и в зависимости от совпадения, обрабатывать запрос?

Comment: Если токен общий для всех, то злоумышленник просто достанет токен из вашего фронтенда

Comment: @andreymal спасибо. Буду думать на этой проблемой дальше

Comment: Последнее предложение *(upd: его уже нет)* в вопросе совершенно непонятно. Что помешает злоумышленнику открыть код компонента и прочитать из него токен? Инспектор для этого не нужен.

Comment: @andreymal про то, что можно считывать компонент не знал. Прошу прощение.

Comment: Тут важно разделить какая часть фронта будет отправлять запросы. Если та, что в начале берет данные, "рендерит" их в HTML, а потом отдает в браузер, тт можно создать секретный ключ, который будет отправляться с каждым запросом. Для дополнительной безопасности, можно еще сделать ограничение по IP и добавить сертификат. В случае, если запрос будет отправляться из браузера, то никак. Тут по определению уже можно считать как доступ извнее.